# Я хочу получить конкретное значение, возращаемое методом

Tags: python, массивы, return

К примеру, вот код:

```
return names_vacancie, urls, prices
```

И вот задача, я хочу получить только значение "urls", можно ли это сделать ? Если можно, то как ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если из функции возвращаете несколько переменных как тут `return names_vacancie, urls, prices`, то их значения вернутся в кортеже (`tuple`):

```
def get() -> tuple:
    names_vacancie, urls, prices = 1, 2, 3
    return names_vacancie, urls, prices

print(type(get()))
# <class 'tuple'>
```

Достать значение можно по индексу:

```
urls = get()[1]
print(urls)
```

Или через распаковку в переменные:

```
names_vacancie, urls, prices = get()
print(urls)

_, urls, _ = get()
print(urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов сделать это:

1. Использовать индекс для доступа к нужному элементу в списке:

```
urls_only = urls[1]
```

1. Использовать присваивание с помощью динамического пакета:

```
_, urls_only, _ = return names_vacancie, urls, prices
```

1. Использовать присваивание с помощью метода pop():

```
urls_only = return names_vacancie, urls, prices.pop(1)
```

1. Использовать присваивание с помощью спискового включения:

```
urls_only = [urls for _, urls, _ in return names_vacancie, urls, prices]
```

1. Использовать присваивание с помощью деструктуризации:

```
urls_only, *_ = return names_vacancie, urls, prices
```

Выберите тот способ, который вам больше нравится или который более удобнее.

Comment: сложно и непонятно